# Should I say "the group concluded his portfolio" or "its portfolio"?

Tags: pronouns

Referring to a group of students, should I say

> the group concluded HIS portfolio

or

> the group concluded ITS portfolio?

Comment: Hello, Celso. Even though the group consists of persons, _its_ (or, especially in the UK, _their_) is used to refer to it/the members. But this question is not suitable for ELU.

Comment: Hi Edwin, thanks for the answer. Why isn't it suitable?

Comment: There are other websites dealing with basic questions; our sister site, ELL, is one.

Comment: Unlike many other languages, English only uses 'gender' for singular things that actually have genitals.

Answer (score 2):

Only when referring to a single person should you use he/him or she/her. When referring to a group, use it. This applies the the possessive as well, so you should use "its".